# How to set Database credentials for different environment in TALEND Open Studio

Tags: data-migration, talend

I have a requirement to set Database connections credentials for my TALEND jobs for different environment as Runtime Values. Means if i want to run my jobs in Development environment, then it should pick DB credentials from a development csv/excel/text file and if i am running it in Production then it should pick credentials from Prod text file. Someone please tell me is this is possible and if yes can someone please guide me how to do this. I read this link but in this i am not able to configure the values in a text/csv file.

http://blog.iadvise.eu/2014/05/27/use-of-contexts-within-talend/

Comment: Are you using an enterprise licensed version of Talend or the Open Studio?

Comment: you should use context groups and implicitly load contexts from file in your job and you can change the context values like dblogin, dbhost, dbport, dbpassword etc in the file for each environment..say  your file is jobcontext.cto - in this file when you run job in dev you put dev credentials, when you run job in prod you put production server credentials

Comment: thanks garpitmzn...but how create and map this file to my jobs...could you please guide me...

Comment: @ydaetskcoR its Open Studio

Answer (score 1):

Use context variables. [This](http://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?idTuto=34) tutorial will help you set up context variable which has different values for different environment. You can have different configuration for different environment for same job.